# Is a tensor product of maps an isomorphism iff maps themselves isomorphisms?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism

Working over vector spaces, let $f:U \longrightarrow U'$, $g: V \longrightarrow V'$. Define $f \otimes g : U \otimes V \longrightarrow U' \otimes V'$ by $(f \otimes g)(u\otimes v) = f(u)\otimes g(v)$.

Then is $f\otimes g$ an isomorphism iff $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms?

(Really, I'm only asking if the forwards direction is true since it's trivial to show that if $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ exist, then $f^{-1}\otimes g^{-1} = (f\otimes g)^{-1}$.)

The analogous question with direct sums is easy to prove, but that because it's easy to restrict a map from direct sum to one of its components; I'm having trouble seeing (assuming it's possible) how to define a map $f^{-1}:U' \longrightarrow U$ from  $(f \otimes g)^{-1}:U'\otimes V' \longrightarrow U\otimes V$.

Comment: If $V$ and $V'$ are zero spaces, then $f \otimes g$ will be a zero map between zero spaces, and thus automatically an isomorphism, no matter what $f$ is. Apart from this trivial counterexample (and the symmetric one you get if $U$ and $U'$ are zero), I think your conjecture is true, although I can only vouch for the case when all four vector spaces are finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are non-zero, and that $f\otimes g$ is an isomorphism (and therefore $U'$ and $V'$ are non-zero).

Then both $f$ and $g$ must be injective, because if $f(u)=0$ for non-zero $u\in U$ then for any non-zero $v\in V$ we would have $(f\otimes g)(u\otimes v)=0$.

Now we wish to prove that $f$ and $g$ are surjective. Let $(u'_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ and extend to a basis $(u'_i)_{i\in J}$ of $U'$. Let $(v'_k)_{k\in K}$ be a basis of $V'$. Then $U'\otimes V'$ has $(u'_i\otimes v'_k)_{i\in J,k\in K}$ as a basis, but the image of $f\otimes g$ is spanned by $(u'_i\otimes v'_k)_{i\in I,k\in K}$, which is a contradiction unless $I=J$.

Comment: I'm confused about "the image of $f\otimes g$ is spanned by ..." line, aren't you already assuming $g$ is surjective?

Comment: @CookieMonster I mean that the image of $f\otimes g$ is a subspace of the span of $(u'_i\otimes v'_k)_{i\in I,k\in K}$. I don't think the words "spanned by" necessarily mean that the given set of vectors lies in the given space.